# Batch tool crashes when I login

Tags: batch-file

So when ever I open my batch tool and login it just crashes. Does anyone know why?
Whenever I provide incorrect credentials it says "The credentials you entered are incorrect, try again." (which is correct) But whenever I type in user = root and pass = root it closes/crashes my batch file.

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
:login
cls
color D
title Multi Tool
echo.
REM echo ██████╗ ██╗      ██████╗  ██████╗ ███╗   ███╗███████╗
REM echo ██╔══██╗██║     ██╔═══██╗██╔═══██╗████╗ ████║██╔════╝
REM echo ██████╔╝██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║██╔████╔██║███████╗
REM echo ██╔══██╗██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║██║╚██╔╝██║╚════██║
REM echo ██████╔╝███████╗╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║ ╚═╝ ██║███████║
REM echo ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚══════╝  
REM echo.          
echo Login here
echo.
set /p user=Enter username:
echo.
set /p pass=Enter password:
if %user% == root if %pass% == root goto main
echo.
echo The credentials you entered are incorrect, try again.
timeout 3 >nul
goto login
:main
cls
REM echo.
REM echo ██████╗ ██╗      ██████╗  ██████╗ ███╗   ███╗███████╗
REM echo ██╔══██╗██║     ██╔═══██╗██╔═══██╗████╗ ████║██╔════╝
REM echo ██████╔╝██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║██╔████╔██║███████╗
REM echo ██╔══██╗██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║██║╚██╔╝██║╚════██║
REM echo ██████╔╝███████╗╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║ ╚═╝ ██║███████║
REM echo ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚══════╝  
REM echo.
echo Welcome to the main tool
```

Comment: When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed.

Comment: But there are no errrors

Comment: @Lunar - [It works fine](https://imgur.com/MAN0AkR), what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer to your question, but does include a `Pause` command at the bottom, to prevent it from closing when invoked via the GUI.

It is more to show you that you should use the `Call` command with a label name whenever you want to show your Art/Banner.

The example below, only changes the active code page, if necessary, and only for the banner portion of your file, returning it to the default code page for the rest of the script. This method is also simpler when you want to test your code without displaying the banner, because you simply need to put a `Rem`ark in front of your `Call :banner` lines instead of every line of every instance of that art.

I've also added a three strike rule for both the `username` and `password` input prompts. This seems to me like a wise idea, as any end user who cannot get it correct in three attempts, probably shouldn't be using it.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Title Multi Tool
Color 0D
GoTo login

:banner
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set _cp) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com"') Do For %%H In (%%G
) Do Set "_cp=%%~nH"
If Not %_cp% Equ 65001 (Set "_cpc=TRUE"
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com" 65001 1> NUL)
Echo=
Echo ██████╗ ██╗      ██████╗  ██████╗ ███╗   ███╗███████╗
Echo ██╔══██╗██║     ██╔═══██╗██╔═══██╗████╗ ████║██╔════╝
Echo ██████╔╝██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║██╔████╔██║███████╗
Echo ██╔══██╗██║     ██║   ██║██║   ██║██║╚██╔╝██║╚════██║
Echo ██████╔╝███████╗╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║ ╚═╝ ██║███████║
Echo ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚══════╝
Echo=
If Defined _cpc ("%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com" %_cp% 1> NUL
    For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set _cp') Do Set "%%G=")
Exit /B

:login
ClS
Call :banner
Echo Login here.
Set "i=0"
Echo=

:getuser
Set /A i += 1
Set "user="
Set /P "user=Enter username: "
Set "user=%user:"=%"
If /I Not "%user%" == "root" If %i% Lss 3 (GoTo getuser
) Else (Echo=
    Echo The username you entered is incorrect, exiting.
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 1> NUL
    GoTo :EOF)
Set "i=0"
Echo=

:getpass
Set /A i += 1
Set "pass="
Set /P "pass=Enter password: "
Set "pass=%pass:"=%"
If /I Not "%pass%" == "root" If %i% Lss 3 (GoTo getpass
) Else (Echo=
    Echo The credentials you entered are incorrect, try again.
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 1> NUL
    GoTo login)
Set "i="
Echo=

:main
ClS
Call :banner
Echo Welcome to the main tool.
Echo=

Pause
```